# Vertical align div to another div (not inside)

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox, css-grid

I have design requirement to align a div to another div just like below figure

- Box 1: dynamic height and width
- Box 2 and 4: dynamic height and fixed width
- Box 3: fix width and height
- Box 1 and box 3 should be vertically aligned with each other

[image]

I already tried with css grid but it doesn't fix to the req. Maybe anyone can have a solution for this? thanks

Comment: box 3 is of fixed height and width while 2 and 4 are of dynamic height, does that mean 2 and 4 heights can affect the positioning of 3, even so you want 1 to be vertically aligned ?

Answer (score 2):

Use CSS grid like below:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  gap: 5px;
  grid-template-rows: auto 80px auto; /* this contain the fixed height of 3 */
}

.container div:nth-child(1) {
  grid-row: 2; /* 1st child in second row */
  align-self: center; 
}

/* 2nd to 4th child in second column */
.container :nth-child(n + 2) {
  grid-column: 2;
}

.container > div {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div style="height: 120px">1</div>
  <div style="height: 50px">2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div style="height: 150px">4</div>
</div>
```